# Inline image data in XSL:FO / Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, pdf, mime, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have MIME Multi-Part data that I want to convert to PDF using XSL:FO. I'm comfortable [reading MIME](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8TMJFU) using [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) and I have a grasp on [embedded image data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) in Mime or [inline images](http://danielmclaren.com/2008/03/embedding-base64-image-data-into-a-webpage) in HTML. I diligently searched SO for ["[xsl-fo] inline graphic"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxsl-fo%5D+inline+graphic) and ["[xsl] +html +mime +image"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxsl%5D+%2Bhtml+%2Bmime+%2Bimage) and found somehow [the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684909/xslt-convert-base64-data-into-image-files) and a [precurser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691983/how-to-encode-a-image-in-xml-file-with-help-of-xslt) what I'm up to. Also [Google on "convert HTML MIME to XSL:FO"](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+HTML+MIME+to+XSL%3AFO) was inconclusive.

What I want to do is having an element (or a set of elements) that render a graphic (JPG/PNG/GIF - all or some of them) in the PDF output of an XSL:FO transformation. The graphic data should be included *inside* the .fo file as Base64 (or otherwise) encoded data. I found how to point to [external graphics](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#fo_external-graphic), but nothing about embedded graphic data.

How would that work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The element `fo:external-graphic` can be utilized to embed inline data as well. Just use the following syntax:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,<DATA>')"/>
```

`<DATA>` should be replaced with your base64 data string of the JPEG image.

Comment: @Martin, can you point to some reference documentation where this is explained? According to the XSL specification, the value of the `src` attribute should be a "uri-specification" (`src=url(...)`).

Comment: @mzjn: You're right. I should have wrapped the `src`value with `url()` to be compliant with the standard. Since I primarily use FOP which  accepts the shorthand form, I didn't thought about the explicit `url()` construct. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Martin for this I get "Image not found. URI: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...". Any idea?