# Use XSL:FO to add attachments to PDF

Tags: xslt, pdf, mime, xsl-fo, apache-fop

After resolving [inline images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372069/inline-image-data-in-xslfo-apache-fop) with help from SO, I need to sort out inline attachments. PDF can contain attachments and I found:[fo:declarations - pdf:embedded-file](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html#pdf-extensions) but again it pointed to an external file. How can I attach a file that is part of a MIME message (most likely BASe64)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest FOP builds, you can use the same syntax for `pdf:embedded-file` as for `fo:external-graphic` and directly append the base64 data:

```
<fo:declarations>
  <pdf:embedded-file filename="myfile.pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,<DATA>"/>
</fo:declarations>
...
<fo:basic-link external-destination="url(embedded-file:myfile.pdf)">Embedded PDF</fo:basic-link>
```

Comment: cool. Does 'latest build' mean I have to compile from source or is a CA. 1 week old binary download OK?

Comment: I don't know exactly when this feature was added. It's not implemented in the 1.0 release but has been present in the trunk for several months now. So, a recent nightly build should be fine.

Comment: Trying to pass base64 data as part of xml and doesn't seem to work, i declared a variable and point it to xml tag with the data and doesn't seem to be used in any way, any ideas?