# SSJS or Java generate PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hello I have an application XPages and now I need to create a button that create PDF that combining in one PDF file sources (XLS, WORD, JPEG, PNG etc..) from a richtext attachments.

Now I think that the best solution is used Acrobat Professional on server ...and the API (server side). But I don't know if this is a good solution.

Anyone has suggestions about this? I think that can I use Java Code (If there are the integration API) I'm looking at now Acrobat website and I see that Acrobat X use Javascript (But do you work only client?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Java, [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) and [Apache pdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) in an XPages project to create pdf files with included/attached files from richtext attachments.

It works well but is a lot of work...

Comment: Hermann: you use this https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithattachments.html for the attachments?

Comment: That might work too but I used FOP for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412030/2065611

Comment: but I need to convert my source attachments in PDF before? How can I do?

Comment: No, the files are included in pdf as MS Word, Excel, png, ... and you can create a "link" to those included files inside your pdf to open them with the connected application like MS Word, Excel, ... This way you don't need to convert the attachments.

Comment: You can convert MS Word, Excel, ... to pdf though with Apache POI. You could merge several pdf files to one pdf file with Apache pdfBox afterwards.